# Python requests doesn't send cookies properly?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a request with cookies with python requests, but it doesn't seem to be sending the cookie

This is the request

```
nyt_stat_url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/svc/crosswords/v3/undefined/puzzles.json'
cookies = {'NYT-S': '<cookie>'}
params = {
        'date_start': '2024-01-01',
        'date_end': '2024-01-26'
    }

response = requests.get(nyt_stat_url, cookies=cookies, params=params)
```

and the response says that I haven't solved any puzzles, but when I do the same request in httpie I get the response that I'm expecting which shows which puzzles I've solved. I've also tried passing the cookie as in as a header and get the same result

```
headers = {'cookie': 'NYT-S=<cookie>'}
response = requests.get(nyt_stat_url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

What do I need to do to send the request correctly?

Comment: Why do you think that requests is causing the problem and not the server?

Comment: @KlausD. I don't know I am learning python and am completely new to this. If it were an issue with the server what could cause this?

Comment: If you where the NT Times would you allow people to fiddle with your puzzle or would you put something in place to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely the bug is in the Python `requests` module. I modified your program to look like this:

```py
import requests
nyt_stat_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/svc/crosswords/v3/undefined/puzzles.json'
cookies = {'NYT-S': '<cookie>'}
params = {
        'date_start': '2024-01-01',
        'date_end': '2024-01-26'
    }

response = requests.get(nyt_stat_url, cookies=cookies, params=params)
```

I then started a netcat process to accept new connections and display the data received:

```
nc -l -4 127.0.0.1 8080
```

In a different window I ran the Python program I created: `python3 x.py`. This is what I saw output by netcat:

```
GET /svc/crosswords/v3/undefined/puzzles.json?date_start=2024-01-01&date_end=2024-01-26 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: python-requests/2.31.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: NYT-S=<cookie>
```

It looks to me like the cookie was correctly included in the HTTP headers. Which means the more likely explanation is the URL is incorrect, the start and end data parameters are incorrect (e.g., wrong date format), or the cookie is incorrect.

P.S., It's also possible that the NYT website has set other cookies that your browser is including in any request it sends and that you have not included in your Python program.

Comment: Yeah I just checked the response headers and the cookie was there so it's not the requests module. But why would the same request give a different response from HTTPie and through the requests module?

Comment: I have no idea what "HTTPie" is. Did you see my updated answer that adds a "P.S." paragraph? One likely explanation is that the NYT is setting one or more cookies it expects to be sent in addition to the cookie you are setting.

Comment: @catlover33 See my previous comment.